# raspberry ap dchp

Tags: dhcp, raspberry-pi, dnsmasq

Hi to all I've made an access point with my raspberry pi and it work flawless but when i install and configure dnsmasq to redirect i receive errors and the ap not work anymore...

if dnsmasq is active dchp say: https://pastebin.com/HsSJsgPd

if dhcp is active dnsmasq say: https://pastebin.com/vxUGiBMR

Thy can't start at the same time... but on every tutorial that I've seen they are running at the same time.

If i stop dnsmasq and run dhcp the ap work well.Thanks for the help and forgive my English but is not my language.

*###########################################################################*

EDIT:
heavyd and Vlastimil Ovčáčík thanks now it work.

GAD3Rn thanks now is resolved but i post the output just to be sure;

isc-dhcp-server:
  Installed: 4.3.1-6+deb8u2
  Candidate: 4.3.1-6+deb8u2
  Version table:
 *** 4.3.1-6+deb8u2 0
        500 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie/main armhf Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

Comment: Both services are trying to bind to the DHCP port.  You need to decide which one you want to handle DHCP and disable DHCP on the other.

Comment: You may find helpful [Disable dhcp service in dnsmasq](https://serverfault.com/q/351962/305324).

Comment: What is the output of `apt-cache policy isc-dhcp-server`? you can edit here: https://superuser.com/posts/1262735/edit